# Unable to serve content from /static URL root in Django development server

Tags: django

I was absolutely baffled for a good 30 minutes, but I think my issues must be related to change in Django 1.3.

My urls.py looks like this:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        (r'^admin_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )
```

If I visit /static/, I get a file listing. For example, in my root directory there is a file "iphone.png". Going to /static/iphone.png I get a 404 message.

If I change that section to:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^otherstatic/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        (r'^admin_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )
```

Everything related to /otherstatic/ works wonderfully.

I should also add there were no problems with /media/ or /admin_media/.

Is this related to Django's new staticfiles app? (If so, who thought it was a good idea to completely break this very simple use case?)

Thanks!

Comment: most probably staticfiles. try to disable them at all.

Comment: it is probably staticfiles, you can disable it or change the static file root url in settings file in order not to clash with your urls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Django 1.3, with `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, the framework will look for all static files under all apps which have a static folder.

[Read the first point, second line carefully](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#using-django-contrib-staticfiles).

Here's an example:

```
project/
    yourapp/
        static/
            iphone.png
    settings.py
```

Assuming `yourapp` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, you should be able to access the `iphone.png` image with just the following url:

```
http://localhost:8000/static/iphone.png
```

For your case, if you want `staticfiles` app to search for files under `project/static/`, you will need to add the following to your `settings.py`:

```
import os
SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

Be careful with the above, make sure that none of the paths in `STATICFILES_DIRS` are a match to the path you set in `STATIC_ROOT`.  The latter is mainly used in production.

Feel free to remove the `static` line from your project `urls.py` after setting `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: Ultimately I think it's because the development server has been changed. I think it's due to the urls.py at contrib/staticfiles/ though I'm not positive. I ended up just removing the contrib.staticfiles from my INSTALLED_APPS, which is the easiest fix. I was just somewhat frustrated about 1.3's defaults breaking what I had been doing since before 1.0.

Comment: Well I have the same problem. I configured my project as you described, but static files still aren't accessible using development server. I had to disable staticfiles app and serve static files the old way, by static.serve . I'm working on Windows at development stage, so maybe it's a platform issue?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Django 1.3?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using a different development server, you shouldn't need to add anything to your urlconf for serving staticfiles in your STATIC_ROOT dir.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#s-static-file-development-view

> This view is automatically enabled by
>   runserver (with a DEBUG setting set to
>   True). To use the view with a
>   different local development server,
>   add the following snippet to the end
>   of your primary URL configuration: